# Mysql #1442 - Can't update table 'stock' in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

My triger It works normally but if i use procedur in the insert I'm getting the error

## 1442 - Can't update table 'stock' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

bu if i use manuel insert into table panier Normal inserted does not show me the error :'(

i use it like that :

```
call temps;
call stock_panier(94,19,'tranche');
call panier_ins(22547153,6185,null,now());
```

my triger :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  Stock_cal BEFORE INSERT on panier
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
  DECLARE is_exist INT;
    DECLARE is_exist1 INT;
      DECLARE is_exist2 INT;
            set is_exist = (select stock.qte_res_s from stock WHERE stock.code_s=new.code_s);
        set is_exist1 = new.qte_p;
        set is_exist2 = new.qte_p;
            if  (is_exist<is_exist1) OR (is_exist2<1) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '✘: Opération a été refusée.';    
                ELSE  
       UPDATE stock SET qte_res_s=qte_res_s-new.qte_p,qte_sor_s=qte_sor_s+new.qte_p WHERE  new.code_s=stock.code_s  ;
       END if;
      
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

my table temperer :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `temps`()
BEGIN
call virifier_table_exist('panier_tm');
if (@table_exists)=0 THEN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `panier_tm` (
      `N_p` bigint(20) DEFAULT Null,
      `N`   bigint(20) DEFAULT null,
        `Code_barr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Référence` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Désignation` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Prix_HT` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Fournisseur` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Magasin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Qte_Vent` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
        `code_s` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `code_d` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        tva_p varchar(5) DEFAULT Null,
        type_ver varchar(15) DEFAULT null);
SET @row_number:=0;
else    
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `panier_tm`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `panier_tm` (
      `N_p` bigint(20) DEFAULT Null,
      `N`   bigint(20) DEFAULT null,
        `Code_barr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Référence` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Désignation` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Prix_HT` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Fournisseur` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Magasin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Qte_Vent` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
        `code_s` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `code_d` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
         tva_p varchar(5) DEFAULT Null,
        type_ver varchar(15) DEFAULT null);
SET @row_number:=0;
        end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

my procedure :

```
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS panier_ins ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE panier_ins (in code_cccp varchar(30), code_cl1 bigint(20),N_p1 bigint(20),dat date)
BEGIN
DECLARE code_faa varchar(20);
DECLARE  n_p2 bigint(20);
START TRANSACTION;
if (SELECT COUNT(Qte_Vent) from panier_tm tm2,stock WHERE tm2.code_s=stock.code_s and tm2.Qte_Vent>stock.qte_res_s and not EXISTS (select 1 from panier_vu vu2 where tm2.N_p=vu2.code_p and tm2.code_s=vu2.code_s ))>0 THEN 
SELECT "Veuillez vous assurer que le stock est terminé" AS message ;
ELSE 
set @count_n_p=(select COUNT(n_p) from panier_tm where n_p=n_p1);
set @n_p=(select n_p from panier_tm where n_p=n_p1);
       if (@n_p) is null OR  (@count_n_p)=0 THEN
     SET @n_p2=(SELECT MIN(t1.code_p+1) as id FROM panier t1 LEFT JOIN panier t2 On t1.code_p+1=t2.code_p Where t2.code_cl IS NULL);
           set @n_p2=if(@n_p2 = null,1,@n_p2);
           INSERT INTO `panier`(`code_p`, `n_p`, `code_s`, `code_cl`, `type_ver_p`, `date_p`, `qte_p`, `prix_p`, `tva_p`) SELECT @n_p2,tm1.n,stock.code_s,code_cl1,type_ver,dat,qte_vent,prix_ht,tva_p FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE    preduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr  and tm1.code_s=stock.code_s and  NOT EXISTS (select 1 from panier_vu vu1 where tm1.N_p=vu1.code_p and tm1.code_s=vu1.code_s);
    update panier_tm set N_p=@n_p2;
   set code_faa=(SELECT MIN(SUBSTRING(t1.code_fa, 6, length(t1.code_fa)-5)+1) as id FROM facture t1 LEFT JOIN facture t2 On SUBSTRING(t1.code_fa, 6, length(t1.code_fa)-5)+1=SUBSTRING(t2.code_fa, 6, length(t2.code_fa)-5) Where t2.code_fa IS NULL);
  set code_faa=  CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%Y"),"/",code_faa) ;
    INSERT INTO `facture`(`autot`, `code_fa`, `code_ccp`, `code_cl`, `code_p`, `date_fa`, `type_ver`) VALUES (null,code_faa,code_cccp,code_cl1,@n_p2,now(),typ);
   COMMIT ;
     ELSE
    START TRANSACTION;
           INSERT INTO `panier`(`code_p`, `n_p`, `code_s`, `code_cl`, `type_ver_p`, `date_p`, `qte_p`, `prix_p`, `tva_p`) SELECT tm1.n_p,tm1.n,stock.code_s,code_cl1,type_ver,dat,qte_vent,prix_ht,tva_p FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE preduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr and tm1.code_s=stock.code_s and  NOT EXISTS (select 1 from panier_vu vu1 where tm1.N_p=vu1.code_p and tm1.code_s=vu1.code_s);
         DELETE b FROM `panier` b LEFT JOIN panier_tm f ON  f.code_s = b.code_s and b.code_p=f.N_p WHERE code_p=n_p1 and f.N_p is null;
          UPDATE `panier` p1,panier_tm tms SET p1.`n_p`=tms.N_p,p1.`qte_p`=tms.Qte_Vent,p1.`prix_p`=tms.Prix_HT,`tva_p`=tva1 WHERE p1.code_p=N_p1 and p1.code_s=tms.code_s;
   COMMIT ;
     END if;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I can''t see nothing that could call this behaviuor. the only trigger Stock_cal  thich updates stock, so as long you don't have a triggerf which calls on a procedure...

Comment: Unless there is another trigger on stock table or panier table that causes this error.

Comment: problem in procedure not in trigger

Comment: i dont have trigger in stock table

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the two inserts into `panier` that depend on `stock`, while you have an `on insert`-trigger on `panier` that modifies the table `stock` that the insert into `panier` depends on:

```
INSERT INTO `panier`(`code_p`, ...) SELECT @n_p2,tm1.n,stock.code_s, ...
FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE reduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr ...

INSERT INTO `panier`(`code_p`, ...) SELECT tm1.n_p,tm1.n,stock.code_s, ...
FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE preduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr ...
```

They both have the structure

```
INSERT INTO panier (...) SELECT ... FROM stock ...
```

which is not allowed if you have an insert trigger on `panier` which modifies `stock`. These inserts are the *statement which invoked this stored function/trigger* in which you *can't update table 'stock'*. MySQL is for technical reasons not able to do this.

The straight forward technical workaround for this is to create a temporary table in which you store the result of your `SELECT ...`, and then insert into panier from that temporary table, e.g. something like

```
 create temporary table tmp (...);
 insert into tmp (...) select ... from stock ...;
 insert into panier (...) select ... from tmp;
 drop table tmp;
```

The insert-trigger now doesn't modify any dependent tables anymore, since you only select from `tmp`.

In your procedure, this would look like

```
 create temporary table tmp (code_p bigint(20), n_p bigint(20), 
 ..., tva_p varchar(5)); 

 if (@n_p) is null OR  (@count_n_p)=0 THEN  
   ...
   insert into tmp (code_p, n_p, ...) 
   SELECT @n_p2,tm1.n,stock.code_s, ...
   FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE reduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr ...

   insert into panier (code_p, n_p, ...) select code_p, n_p, ... from tmp;
   ...
else  
   ...
   insert into tmp (code_p, n_p, ...) 
   SELECT tm1.n_p,tm1.n,stock.code_s, ...
   FROM `preduit`,`stock`,`panier_tm` tm1 WHERE preduit.code_pr=stock.code_pr ...

   insert into panier (code_p, n_p, ...) select code_p, n_p, ... from tmp;
   ...
end if; 
drop table tmp;
```

You can of course create the temporary table in your procedure `temps`.

It is also usually possible to redesign your procedure, triggers or logic so you do not need this, but that would probably be a larger endeavour.

And you should verify if that is actually the logic you want to apply, e.g. if you want to decide on the current state of `stock` which rows to insert, freeze this state (by putting it into the `tmp`-table) and then run the insert independently of how the `stock`-table changed during those inserts (e.g. if you would have inserted the 2nd row if you would have known what the first row changed in `stock`). I didn't check what your code is supposed to do, so this may or may not apply here, and may or may not be a problem here, but circular dependendies (and the error you get here because of it) can sometimes be a sign for an underlying problem.

Comment: pls can you mor info :( ?

Comment: The code does already create a temporary table and stores the results

Comment: Yes, but not for the 2 specific inserts which cause the problem. Those use `insert into panier select from stock`. This is not allowed. You need to do: `insert into tmp select from stock; insert into panier select from tmp`. I hope I made it more specific now.

Comment: Thank you brother for intervening, yes I did not notice that the mistake was there